# Coloring a Grid

Tags: java, grid

So I am trying to color a grid to make it look like a flag. The top half of the "flag" is red, while the bottom portion of the "flag" is white. So far I have the code as follows:

```
public class FlagMaker {
    public static void drawFlag(MyGrid grid, int countryCode) {
        int width = grid.getWd();
        int height = grid.getHt();
        if (countryCode == 1) {
            for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < height; rowNum++) {
                for (int colNum = 0; colNum < width; colNum++) {
                    grid.setColor(rowNum, colNum, Color.RED);
                }
            }
            for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum > height ; rowNum++) {
                for (int colNum = 0; colNum > width; colNum++)
                grid.setColor(rowNum/2, colNum, Color.WHITE);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code only colors the whole flag red, and I am stuck on how to get the lower half of the flag to be white. Thanks for any help.

Comment: One would guess that maybe you need to use `int height = grid.getHt() / 2;` so you only cover half the rows...

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class FlagMaker {
    public static void drawFlag(MyGrid grid, int countryCode) {
        int width = grid.getWd();
        int height = grid.getHt();
        if (countryCode == 1) {
            for (int rowNum = 0; rowNum < height/2; rowNum++) {
                for (int colNum = 0; colNum < width; colNum++) {
                    grid.setColor(rowNum, colNum, Color.RED);
                }
            }
            for (int rowNum = height/2; rowNum < height ; rowNum++) {
                for (int colNum = 0; colNum < width; colNum++) {
                    grid.setColor(rowNum/2, colNum, Color.WHITE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```